# Image to base64 encoding issue - PHP

Tags: php

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: image/jpeg;charset=utf-8'");
   $path = 'example/source.jpg';
   $da = file_get_contents($path);

   $base64 = base64_encode($da);
   $src = 'data:image/jpeg;charset=utf-8;base64,'.$base64;
   echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';

?>
```

php v5.6.2

I tired copying the $src value in debug and pasted in img src value. still its not showing up.

what did i missed here?.

thanks in advance

Comment: your code is correct, but maybe because of two reason your code is not working
1. your base64 encode is wrong
2. your image meme type is not jpeg

Comment: Thanks. Found.content-type should be like this header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8'");

Answer (score 1):

> header("Content-type: image/jpeg;charset=utf-8");

here you say to the browser `i will send you an jpeg image`, 
then:

```
echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
```

here you send HTML.

because you said it was a jpeg image, the browser will try to render your *html* as *jpeg*. since the ascii text-based HTML format is *completely incompatible* with the binary based jpeg-format, the browser will fail horribly when trying to render your *image*, and fail with some error (probably `image is corrupt` or something like that.)

you can either fix your `Content-Type` header to specify that you're sending HTML, then the browser will (probably successfully!) try to render it as such, eg:

```
header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

or you can modify your code to actually send the image as jpeg, eg:

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
   $path = 'example/source.jpg';
   readfile($path);
```

(btw a base64 encoded jpeg image will be about 33% larger than just the raw jpeg image, so if you want a fast pageload, or you want to save up on bandwidth, or you want to save up on ram, using readfile() is faster, requires less bandwidth, and requires less ram, both for the server and the client, compared to your embedded base64 approach.)

Comment: Thanks.. It worked with this.. header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");

Answer (score 0):

So maybe your problem is in your mime type. then try this code two solve:

```
$path = 'domain.com/example/source.jpg';

$content = file_get_contents($path);
$file_info = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($path));
$base64 = base64_encode($content);
$src = 'data:'.$mime_type.';charset=utf-8;base64,'.$base64;
echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
```

Note: its better to use path from full address domain, if you want to use from path use  [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.readfile.php)